# \overline{} in Matplotlib Not Working

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Background: here is a minimum working example that produces the error:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,2],label=r"$\alpha$")
plt.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,2],label=r"$\overline{a}$") #This is the offending line
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Running this produces the following error message after a fairly long `Traceback` list:

```
pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Expected end of math '$'
$\overline{a}$ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

I also got this warning which I am not sure is connected with my problem since it happens whether or not I include the "offending line" in my script:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1242: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['cmb10'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1252: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=12. Returning /usr/share/fonts/un-core/UnDotum.ttf  UserWarning)
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1242: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['cmtt10'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1242: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['cmss10'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

If I do not include the "offending line" as I've specified it to be above then everything works fine. I've tried a variety of things not shown here which have led me to conclude that the problem centers around `\overline{}`.  However, I do not know why it isn't working, since the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial) says that `\overline{}` should work once it is put inside `$$`.

Previously I have used `plt.rc('text',usetex=True)` to fix this but now I am working on plots that I plan on including in a publication and I am working on fine-tuning the font size and style for best readability and using `plt.rc('text',usetex=True)` forces my tick labels to use the default LaTeX font instead of the one I want to use.

Python version: 2.6.6

Comment: For what it's worth, try `\bar{a}`.

Comment: That works but it doesn't look nice.  The bar doesn't center on the letter it's over.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib do you use? On my machine with matplotlib v1.4 it works fine.

Comment: 1.0.1 is my Matplotlib version.  Seems I should try updating it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code snippet and it seemed to work for me.

[image]

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? 
python verions: 2.7
matplotlib version: 1.3.1.

Comment: It is what I am trying to accomplish.  However, just showing me that it works for you doesn't help me.

Comment: haha, sorry to add to your frustrations. At the time of my posting this you had not revealed your matplotlib version.  The picture was to verify that I  understood the question. the versions at the bottom of the post were to identify if we were working in the same environment. It would appear the packages were quite possibly the source of your problems. sorry it was not more straight forward. good luck with your pythoning  :)